# jQuery - prepending & appending html to a form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm using a timeline in Rails, where if you put blockquote tags around the stuff you write in the media field, it will create a quote styling on the timeline. What I'm trying to achieve is to have a checkbox, so that if it is checked, it will add the blockquote tags for you, so that users don't have to be expected to write html.

How do I add the blockquote tags around whatever they write before it is submitted, but only if the checkbox is checked? I was experimenting with trying to just get the jQuery to pre/append the tags to the input field, so that they were visible to the user, but I can't get that working either. Preferrably, though, I would like it so that the user never sees the html (in case they accidentally edit it!), and so that their input is simply added to before it is sent to the database.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#blockCheck").bind('click', function(){
        var input = $('#event_media input');
        if ($(this).prop('checked')){
            input.prepend('<blockquote>').append('</blockquote>');
        }
    });
});
```

The checkbox has an id of "blockCheck" and the input field has an id of "event_media". Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This will probably be useful: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: you cannot append/prepend html elements to the value of an input field. You can just manipulate the text content using `.val()`.

Comment: Yes, that looks like what I am after - couple of questions though: Do I need to reload anything via AJAX, or will this automatically be added to the HTML without any refresh/XHR call needed? Also, is there an equivalent 'unwrap' for if the checkbox is unchecked, or would I need to do some sort of div removal? Thanks.

Comment: Hang on, sorry - it's not the whole input I'm trying to wrap i.e. not <blockquote><input....></input></blockquote>, rather, trying to edit the actual contents of whatever the user has typed, so that their input is wrapped by the blockquote tags. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add back-quotes to the input value.

Code(updated to remove quotes if present) [link](http://jsfiddle.net/WjRex/3/)

```
$("a#sub").click(function() {
    var text = $("input").val();    
    $("div").html($("<blockquotes>").html(text));
});

$("a#rem").click(function() {
    var blockquotes = $("div blockquotes");
    var text = $(blockquotes).text(); //you have the text inside the blockquotes

    blockquotes.replaceWith(text); //this to replace or $(blockquotes).remove(); to remove it.

    //alert(html);
});
```

​

HTML

```
<input name="test">
<a id="sub">Submit</a>
<a id="rem">Remove</a>

<br/><br/>
<div></div>
```

​
​

Comment: No sorry, that didn't work. Tried saving the record as well, and it still hadn't put the tags around. Do I need to make some AJAX call to refresh the input field for the blockquotes to actually appear?

Comment: I'm pretty much just after what you can do on this site - in the text editor when you answer a question, you can click a button and it adds the blockquote around your text. I was looking for the javascript equivalent.

Comment: OK. then simply do this `var text = $("input").val();
    $("input").val("\`"+text+"\`");` Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WjRex/1/)

Comment: That works great for that example, thanks. Will try and get that working in this case. Is there any way of doing the reverse - i.e. taking the blockquote tags back off?

Comment: @devnull69 - yep your right. Misread the question. Check the updated answer.